# Pandas and finance calculations

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am fairly new to using Python, and I am working on a stock analysis script.
The idea is that the script will eventually take in a stock symbol, and the script will calculate Sharpe ratio, Treynor ratio, and other financial information.
Right now, I am having trouble getting Pandas to work properly. I am unable to access just a column from the DataFrame to calculate yield for a stock.

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import date, timedelta



def calc_yield(now, old):
    return (now-old)/old


def yield_array(cl):
    array = []
    count = 0
    for i in cl:
        old = cl[count]
        count += 1
        new = cl[count]
        array.append(calc_yield(new, old))
    return array


market = '^GSPC'
ticker = "AAPL"
days = 10

# set start and end dates
edate = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
sdate = edate - timedelta(days=days)

# Read the stock price data from Yahoo
data = DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start=sdate, end=edate)

close = data['Adj Close']


print yield_array(close)
```

Error:

```
/Users/Tim/anaconda/bin/python "/Users/Tim/PycharmProjects/Test2/module tests.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tim/PycharmProjects/Test2/module tests.py", line 35, in <module>
    print yield_array(close)
  File "/Users/Tim/PycharmProjects/Test2/module tests.py", line 16, in yield_array
    new = cl[count]
  File "/Users/Tim/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 484, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Users/Tim/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 1243, in get_value
    return _maybe_box(self, Index.get_value(self, series, key), series, key)
  File "/Users/Tim/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1202, in get_value
    return tslib.get_value_box(s, key)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 540, in pandas.tslib.get_value_box (pandas/tslib.c:11833)
  File "tslib.pyx", line 555, in pandas.tslib.get_value_box (pandas/tslib.c:11680)
IndexError: index out of bounds

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  What output are you getting and how is this different than what you expected?

Comment: I am getting IndexError: index out of bounds. I am hoping the for loop will stop after iterating through all rows within 'close'

Comment: On what line?  Can you provide the whole error message?  Please edit the original question and put the error message there.

Comment: OK. added error message to question. First time using this site, thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem.  Given this function:

```
def yield_array(cl):
    array = []
    count = 0
    for i in cl:
        old = cl[count]
        count += 1
        print count
        new = cl[count]
        array.append(calc_yield(new, old))
        print old
        print new
    return array
```

The problem is that on the last item of `cl`, you will add 1 to `count`, which will result in an index one greater than the maximum index of `cl`.  This results in an error, because it is trying to access an index that doesn't exist.  You would need to do something like `for i in cl[:-1]`, which would skip the last element.

However, there is a much simpler way to do this by vectorizing.  You can reduce this whole function to:

```
close = data['Adj Close']
yield_data = close.diff()/close.shift(1)
```

or better yet, you can put the result back in the `DataFrame` for later use:

```
close = data['Adj Close']
data['Yield'] = close.diff()/close.shift(1)
```

Comment: wow! OK. I see what you mean about iterating beyond the index.Let me do some research on vectors and see what I can figure out. I appreciate the assistance!